# Django rest framework API calling to another API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 django project API. What i am trying to do is django 1 api call to django 2 api to create and appointment (to do a get and post method)

These are the 2 things i am currently 
1. Djangp api 1 will do a get request to django api 2 to get a 200OK response first(for now is just doing testing for 200 status code).

2. Django api 1 will do a post request to django api 2 to create an appointment, getting a queue number if success.

I found an answer here: [Calling a REST API from django view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663945/calling-a-rest-api-from-django-view)

It is working for now but is it a good solution ?

Comment: Yes, it's a good solution. Please don't post new questions to ask if the solution to another question is OK. If you are unsure about the quality of an answer, comment on the answer itself.