# How can I invoke remote api in django view.py?

Tags: python, django, api

I Have a Django app which use api written i ASP.Net. I can call api from template (html page). Is there any way to call api from views.py? I have tried this.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.

def categorydashboard(request):
     r = request.get('xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/Category/getSubCategoryNamev2', d=request.GET)
     return render (request,'categoryDashboard.html',{})
```

API sample data (**it is a GET request**)

```
[
    {
        "category_id": 2,
        "category_name": "Hyper Mechanical",
        "Image_Path": null,
        "subcategory": [
            {
                "category_id": 0,
                "category_name": null,
                "product_subcategory_id": 37,
                "product_subcategory_name": "Lift",
                "schema_id": null,
                "Image_path": ""
            }
          ]
       }
]
```

Server runs well but when i call 'categorydashboard' view its throws following error
**AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'**
**I am new in Django so i am sorry if i have mistaken**

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663945/calling-a-rest-api-from-django-view , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259452/proper-way-to-consume-data-from-restful-api-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use an external library like [**`requests`**](https://pypi.org/project/requests/). For example:

```
import requests
def categorydashboard(request):
     r = requests.get('xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/Category/getSubCategoryNamev2', params=request.GET)
     return render (request,'categoryDashboard.html', context={'subcategory':r.json()})
```

Comment: I am getting **context must be a dict rather than list.**