# How to consume REST API in Wagtail CMS

Tags: rest, api, external, wagtail

I would like to invoke an external REST API in Wagtail CMS. Let us assume the URL is:

```html
http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees
```

I tried to follow a **Django** post which was doing almost the same. See:
[Proper way to consume data from RESTFUL API in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259452/proper-way-to-consume-data-from-restful-api-in-django)

I created services.py:

```py
//services.py

import requests

def get_employees(page, request):
    url = 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees' 
    r = requests.get(url)
    employees = r.json()
    return employees
```

I added the following to models.py:

```py
from . import services as services

class HomePage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):

    @route(r'^employees/$')
    def employees_page(self,request):
        employees = services.get_employees(self, request)
        return render(request,'home/employees.html',employees)
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
  File "/data/swag/home/models.py", line 53, in employees_page
    employees = services.get_employees(self, request)
  File "/data/swag/home/services.py", line 13, in get_employees
    employees = r.json()
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/wadmin/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/wadmin/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/wadmin/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/envs/wadmin/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

It seems the Django code does not work in Wagtail and needs to be adapted. I spent several hours looking for an equivalent but no success. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: This error indicates that the response returned by the API is not valid JSON. Are you sure the original Django code works for the URL you're testing against?

Comment: @gasman, the API [link](http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees) is a dummy example REST API. I am using it to learn how to invoke REST API from models.py. I examined the HTTP Response headers for that URL in Chrome and it showed `content-type:application/json; charset-utf-8`. However when I print `r.headers['content-type']` in Wagtail it displays `text/html; charset=iso-8859-1` and `r.encoding` displays `iso-8859-1`.

I also tried setting the following:
`

Comment: Tried the following:
`headers = {'content-type':'application/json; charset-utf-8', 'encoding':'charset-utf-8' }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)`
but it still displays `text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: I could **not** get the above api to work. However, I was able to get the following api to work:
```url = 'https://api.github.com/events'
```
It would be great if someone could explain why the github REST API is different from the dummy REST API above.