# Django and Printful Integration

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm a Jr Python/Django developer, and I'm starting Django E-commerce project, using print on demand Printful tools, I will use the Printfull API.
I can't find a way to test my API Key, on my script.
Some of you can tell me where I can find more information about this integration?
Thank you.
Flavio

```py
import json
import requests

key = ('mwi4tpvh-j0ka-pwsk:dgj0-83boo2cnfog2')
r = requests.get('https://api.printful.com/sync/products')
packages_json = r.key.json()

print(packages_json)
```

Comment: It's an API. Figure out if how you want to handle billing, user ordering, order dispatching, etc. Have a Redis queue for handling the order processing. There's a lot to unpack here and the question needs to be more focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing by "finding more information about this integration" you mean the [Printful API reference](https://www.printful.com/docs)?

If you don't know how to build a DRF API that consumes another service API I suggest [reading this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259452/proper-way-to-consume-data-from-restful-api-in-django)

Although, your question itself is too broad. There is a whole level of architecture that you can design to achieve your goal, but the question that I previously linked should be a good start.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm was looking to one starting point. You gave me that.